# Migrating applications from Oracle Weblogic platform to Red Hat Jboss

Tags: jboss, weblogic8.x

I did some research on this and found many documents for planning and analysis of migration. Is there any document available which describes how to perform the migration? Is this something we can do ourselves as software programmers or do we need to hire a consultant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to read this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebLogic+to+AS+7) before paying someone else :)

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this kind of document.

Comment: @foch: this answer would probably be more handy if you were to discuss the main points inside your answer. otherwise, link rot could make the answer invalid....